# How can I send one alert from my Node.JS to my Javascript client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a basic login from my node.js with mysql.

In my code example, if the session is correct send me to an html page called "home", but for this case, I need that once you make the session, my Javascript client sends an alert that says you have logged in or if its user is incorrect. And if it is correct, save the word "correct" in a variable that I can later use in my javascript file

How could I send that execution, so that my javascript file sends an alert?

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
var username = request.body.username;
var password = request.body.password;
if (username && password) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', 
        [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect('/home'); //Here I want to change the instruction so that my javascript file sends an alert and create a varible that I can use in my file Javascript
        } else {
            console.log('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
        }           
        response.end();
    });
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using a template engine ?

Comment: @Chiller no, how can I use that?

Comment: `response.json({message: "your message goes here", status: 200 //4XX for any error})` then in javascript (front-end) you will get in `then` or `catch` based on your response.

Comment: @ShaileshRathod, Do you have any example?

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro How do you manage your front-end, do you use any framework, or just send static html files by NodeJS?

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak In node I use body-parser  `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("./public"));`, and my javascript

Comment: @IsaacAlejandro That is not what I am asking. In your '/home' route, do you send HTML file, or respond with JSON object?

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak JSON object

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dirty trick you can use,but it will re-render the ejs view:

*On server end(using express):*

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
    res.render('view', { errormessage: 'your message' });
});
```

*On client side(using ejs templates):*

1.create an invisible div on your ejs template ,to access your ejs variable sent by server:

HTML:

```
  <div id='status' class='invisible'><%= errormessage %></div>
```

CSS:

```
.invisible {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
   }
```

2.add this js script(jquery) at end of ejs to access this variable and create an alert:

```
<script>
      if($('div#status').text()!='')
      {
                alert($('div#status').text());
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly execute code on client side, by sending a directive from the server. What you want to do, is to send an **information**, and interpret it properly on the client.

For instance, you can use sessions

```
if (results.length > 0) {
     request.session.loggedin = true;
     request.session.username = username;
     request.session.makeAlert = true;
     response.redirect('/home');
}
```

In the /home route

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    const dataYouSend = {};
    if (req.session.makeAlert) dataYouSend.makeAlert = true;
    res.send(dataYouSend);
});
```

And finally in the JS code on /home route, use your data

```
fetch('adress/to/your/home')
.then(response => {
     // It may not be precisely this, I don't know how you send data
  if (response.makeAlert) alert("Alert!!!");
})
.catch(err => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: how could be the fetch?

Answer (score 0):

At server side(Express middleware):

```
if(userNotExist) return res.status(401).end('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
```

Handle at Client side.

***Angular:-***

```
$http().....
.error(function(data, status) {
  console.error('Repos error', status, data);//"Repos error" 500 "User already exists."
});
```

***jQuery:-***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    success: function (data, text) {
        //success code here.
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        //error handling here.
    }
});
```